# Add custom behavior to Electron menu item with role

Tags: electron

I have an Electron app with a menu item that has the `reload` role. I want to *add* behavior to the standard reload handler - I want the reload handler to work and reload the app, but I also want to do something else. Adding a `click` handler to the menu item didn't work, the handler is not called.

Is there any way to add behavior to a menu item with a role? Or maybe call the default role behavior from my own event handler?

Comment: I can think of a hacky way to do this using a hidden menu item with a role and `robotjs` to press the hidden menu item accelerator. Your visible menu item will do the custom behavior then activate the hidden role menu item via `robotjs`.

Comment: It's a lot simpler to just implement the default behavior in my own handler (it is really just one line of code in my case), I was hoping for a better way.

Comment: I agree. My suggestion is very hacky and I don't recommend it but it's a way to do exactly what you asked about. If you want to implement any custom behavior I don't think you should be using `role`.